# Why is this Typescript module importing and then reexporting another module?

Tags: typescript, module

I am looking to understand further the purpose of [this code](https://github.com/denolibs/event_emitter/blob/master/mod.ts):

```
// Re-export default export
import Default from "./lib/mod.ts";
export default Default;

// Re-export all other exports
export * from "./lib/mod.ts";

// Execute
import "./lib/mod.ts";
```

`.lib/mod.ts` is basically:

```
class MyClass {
...
}

export default MyClass;
```

Is this a common pattern?  What is its purpose?  Why not just `export class MyClass { ... }` in `./lib/mod.ts` and then `import { MyClass } from './lib/mod.ts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only thing this file does is provide an import alias for other modules to import. For example, if this was the directory structure:

- some_dir

  - index.ts
  - lib/

    - mod.ts

Then instead of:

```
import MyClass, { other, stuff } from './some_dir/lib/mod'
```

You could:

```
import MyClass, { other, stuff } from './some_dir'
```

Or it could be used for a published `npm` package, where the implementation is in a sub directory, but the author wants you to import from the package name, and not have to provide sub directories. Such as:

```
import MyClass, { other, stuff } from 'some-npm-package-name'
```

Comment: Ah, the npm package style makes some sense.  You can put implementations in sub directories while still having a top level package name import.  thanks.